Why does a Next.js 15 Fetch URL in production on Fly.io change?
When fetching a post on a production next.js 15 hosted on Fly.io the URL that place in the fetch is changing & causing a 404 not found;
The request URL in the network tab of the Chrome dev tools is:
https://www.rleaguez.com/organizationz/www.rleaguez.com/api/v2/organization

In console log I log out the URL I am using and it’s:
https:www.rleaguez.com/api/v2/organization

The fetch code I am using is:
  const postUrl = 'https:www.rleaguez.com/api/v2/organization';
  console.log(" ~ CreateOrg ~ postUrl:", postUrl)
  const orgResponse = await fetch(
    postUrl,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    },
  );

If the URL is hardcoded such as the code block below the post is successful:
  const orgResponse = await fetch(
    // hardcoded url below is successful
    ‘https://www.rleaguez.com/api/v2/organization’,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    },
  );

Why does the URL change in production and does not stay the same as what I place in the code?

What happens when you replace process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL + '/api/v2/organization' with the correct URL?

the postUrl is set to the correct url which should be https:www.rleaguez.com/api/v2/organization & that is what it's set to; however in the network tab it gets changed & don't know why

It looks like process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_UR is wrong. The console.log output is wrong and fetch tries to fix it. https:www.rleaguez.com/api/v2/organization is not a correct URL.

Thanks @jabaa for the comments; I updated the question a bit to make it more clear and removed the process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL; if the postUrl variable is set to just a string without using the .env var it's still not valid;

If you still don't understand the problem, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#syntax. https:www.rleaguez.com/api/v2/organization is not a correct URL. As you can see in your question, even Stack Overflow can't handle it.

Don't you see the difference between https://www.rleaguez.com/api/v2/organization and https:www.rleaguez.com/api/v2/organization?

@jabaa oh my; I see it now the double slash was missed! that was the issue; thank you;

I greatly appreciate Jabaa's assitance explaining the URL was not valid as it was missing the // after the https: in the URL;
After updating the URL to
const postUrl = 'https://www.rleaguez.com/api/v2/organization';

from
const postUrl = 'https:www.rleaguez.com/api/v2/organization';

that corrected the issue; I guess since it was an invalid URL then the post url was changed to use the page I was on to prefice the posting url.
